# How to avoid complex initial state declaration in React

Tags: reactjs

If I'm, using complex object Structure in React render, how can I avoid redefining that structure in getInitialState method

```
var UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      user:{
        section: {
          country: 'Iran'
        }
      },
      lastGistUrl: ''
    };
  },
....
....
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.user.section.country}'s Amex Initial
        <a href={this.state.lastGistUrl}>here</a>.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Now the problem is the actual structure of the object used is pretty huge

```
user:{
 section: {
   .....
   25 levels of nesting
   .....{
         country: 'Iran'
        }
   }
}
```

and that object is coming from backend , so how can I avoid defining the entire object structure in `getInitialState()`

Comment: why would you define it there in the first place?

Comment: States is for states, not data.

Comment: if you simply `return { user : backendUser };` then you get all the 25 nestings as well. You can then still do `this.state.user.section.country`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, state should be shallow. You shouldn't have deep objects as props or state.

Next, why do you even want to do this? Is it so that you don't get a bunch of "xx is not defined" errors on the initial render? If so, why don't you just declare `user: {}` in `getInitialState`, and wrap an `if (!_.isEmpty(this.state.user))` condition around your render code?

Or, since the data is coming from the server, maybe it's a good thing to re-declare this structure. You can use `getInitialState` to create placeholder data until the real object shows up.

Also, be aware that `setState` only does a shallow replacement. If you change any property or sub-property of the `user` object, you'll need to clone it, change the property, and then call `setState({user: clonedAndUpdatedUser})`. Or, just call `forceUpdate`.

You should really just try to get your props and state to be shallow.

Good luck!

Comment: Existence of state property check, inside render, works . Thanks